# Search iTunes Music Library for a search term via API

Tags: php, json, curl, itunes

All,
I'm trying to allow a user to search for a song. Say the user is searching for Jack Johnson and I want to display all of the songs on iTunes by Jack Johnson. I know I need to construct a URL like the following:

http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=25&media=music&entity=musicArtist,musicTrack,album,mix,song

From a programming persepective, how would I send this to Apple? If I copy that URL into my browser I get some results. Based on those results, how could I parse those results so that I can display them back to the user? Would I want to use JSON, cURL, a combination of the two? What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, maybe something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['term']))
{
    $term = urlencode($_POST['term']); // user input 'term' in a form
    $json =  file_get_contents('http://itunes.apple.com/search?term='.$term.'&limit=25&media=music&entity=musicArtist,musicTrack,album,mix,song');    
    $array = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach($array['results'] as $value)
    {
        echo '<p>';
        echo $value['artistName'].'<br />';
        echo $value['artistLinkUrl'].'<br />';
        echo $value['primaryGenreName'];
        echo '</p>';
    }
}
?> 

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="term" /><input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

For more $array value, try `print_r($array);`

Comment: I tried to do this with a foreach loop but it keeps giving me an error. I tried this code:

    $json =  file_get_contents('http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=25&media=music&entity=musicArtist,musicTrack,album,mix,song');

    $itunes_results = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach ( $itunes_results->results as $results )
    {
        echo "{$results->artistName}\n";
    }

Any ideas on why this won't work?

Comment: how can i download song from itune in php

Answer (score 1):

You would use `file_get_contents` and parse the result with `json_decode`.

```
$js= json_decode(file_get_contents('http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=25&media=music&entity=musicArtist,musicTrack,album,mix,song'));
```

`$js` would now be an array with all the information apple returned.

Comment: Thanks, do you have have an example on how to read the returned json results based on the search string in the question?

Comment: @user1048676, There, I updated my answer. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

The request must be performed over HTTP. JSON is only a format for the data it returns, not a method of retrieving it.

There are many ways you could fetch that data.

The simplest option is simply to use `file_get_contents` if your server has fopen wrappers enabled (it likely does).

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=25&media=music&entity=musicArtist,musicTrack,album,mix,song');
```

cURL is also an option using something like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=25&media=music&entity=musicArtist,musicTrack,album,mix,song");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Once you've retrieved the contents of that page, unserializing it is easy as long as you have the JSON extension installed. If you're using PHP 5.2.0+, then it's part of the core. Otherwise you need to install the PECL module. [See the PHP manual page on the extension for more information.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

```
$response = json_decode($data);
var_dump($response);
```

The unserialized data is an object. You could use it like so:

```
foreach ($response->results as $result)
{
    echo "Artist: ".$result->artistName."<br />".PHP_EOL;
}
```